# I need to create a part where the target I shot is at

Tags: vector, lua, roblox

It's easy to understand. I want to make it so everytime my shot does NOT land on a target (ex: a player), a rounded, grey part appears where my shot hit, in the obstruction, the way Counter-Strike does.

My code consists of a LocalScript, which, when the player holds the left mouse button one down, fires a RemoteEvent, which is picked by a Script and creates the hypothetic ball.

I tried substracting the direction-i-shot's Z value and subtract it by that of the object I shot, accidentally (you are supossed to shot at the target, not at the wall, you know), and sending that vector3 value to a script, so it could create the ball. However, the splinters end up appearing in a strange location, usually far away from the obstruction and to its far left or right.

The code in question:

```
if raycast then
                
                local mf = raycast.Instance.Position
                local hitCharacter = raycast.Instance.Parent
                local diferencia = Vector3.new(direction.X, direction.Y, direction.Z - mf.Z)
                local shot = hitCharacter:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
                
                print ("donde disparaste:", direction)
                print("donde esta lo que disparaste:", mf)
                print ("diferencia entre lo q disparé y donde disparé:", diferencia)
                
                if shot then
                    if hitCharacter.Name ~= player.Character.Name then
                        baleado:FireServer(tool, shot, damage)
                    end
                elseif not shot then
                    esquirla:FireServer(startPosition, diferencia)
                end
                
            end
```

The script, which catches the remote event fired in the LocalScript:

```
local remoteEvent = script.Parent.esquirlaEvent
local tool = script.Parent
local debris = game:GetService("Debris")

remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, startPosition, diferencia)

    local function crearescombros(startPosition, diferencia)
        local center = startPosition + diferencia / 2
        local distance = diferencia.Magnitude
    
        local visual = Instance.new("Part")
        visual.Parent = game.Workspace.linea
        visual.Anchored = true
        visual.CanCollide = false
        visual.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Medium stone grey")
        visual.Material = Enum.Material.Plastic
        visual.Transparency = .4
        visual.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        
        visual.CFrame = CFrame.new(center, startPosition)
        visual.Size = Vector3.new(10, 10, 10)
        
        debris:AddItem(visual, .050)
    end

    
    crearescombros(startPosition, diferencia)
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how startPosition is created, as I do not see it in your code snippet.
However, you don't have to calculate anything. The RaycastResult, which you call "raycast" in your code holds the property "Position" (raycast.Position), this returns the Vector3 position value where the raycast hit. This position can directly be used to place the ball instance there.

Comment: I swapped the variable "diferencia" for "hit", which stands for raycast.Position, as you've told me. However, it does not work, either. although the grey ball no longers clips trough the floor, it keeps appearing in random places and NOT where I shot at. And by the way, startPosition is the place where the raycast starts from, this being the tip of the weapon I'm holding.

Comment: Please edit your comment to add the modified code where you swapped the variable, and defined the hit variable.

Comment: I can't, I reach the max characters available when coping the code. It's exactly the same, but in the second script, swap every instance of "diferencia" for "hit".

and hit is: local hit = raycast.Position

Comment: If you want to have the ball part exactly where the Raycast hit, you did it incorrectly. Currently it will be placed in the middle between the hit and the start position, as you're doing startPosition + hit (end position), divided by two.

Replaced CFrame.new with CFrame.lookAt(hit, startPosition). And see what happens.

Although, I do not know why you want to use a CFrame lookat method, since it's a ball.

Comment: Thanks! it did work, although I now have a different problem, and a question. Although the ball now appears where my raycast hit, when I hold click (auto-fire the gun), the ball keeps appearing closer and closer the more I hold it. And, how do you consider this code would be "better"? the cframes are there in first reason as, then, I used another kind of part, a ray, which would start where the raycast did, and finish where the raycast did, too.

Comment: Please make a second thread for your second question.